# ¿Como puedo hacer un Desplazamiento Automático de Scroll Panel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Alguien sabría decirme como realizar el desplazamiento automático de Scroll Panel a la ultima posición, estoy agregando información y al panel en tiempo real, pero me gustaría que el scroll siempre se fuera a la ultima posición

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un datagrid por ejemplo sería así:

```
dataGridViewNotas.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridViewNotas.RowCount - 1;
```